# Cannot install phpMyAdmin

Tags: jdk, phpmyadmin, oracle

I have installed phpMyAdmin in **Ubuntu 14.04** before, but now it seems like it's not possible. I am stuck with some oracle-java6-installer `404 Not Found` error.

I have run `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin` as usual, but the following error occurs and the installation fails.

```
Preparing to unpack .../phpmyadmin_4%3a4.0.10-1_all.deb ...  
Unpacking phpmyadmin (4:4.0.10-1) ...  
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...  
Processing triggers for doc-base (0.10.5) ...  
Processing 1 added doc-base file...  
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...  
Setting up oracle-java6-installer (6u45-0~webupd8~8) ...  
Downloading Oracle Java 6...  
--2017-10-25 09:13:20--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u45-b06/jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin  
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 184.25.108.41, 184.25.108.17  
Connecting to download.oracle.com   (download.oracle.com)|184.25.108.41|:80... connected.  
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily  
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u45-b06/jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin [following]  
--2017-10-25 09:13:20--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u45-b06/jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin  
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 23.65.97.122, 2600:140f:b:184::2d3e, 2600:140f:b:183::2d3e  
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com   (edelivery.oracle.com)|23.65.97.122|:443... connected.  
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily  
Location: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u45-b06/jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin?AuthParam=1508903146_f5ba776a72e71785aa3526c9fb49f911 [following]  
--2017-10-25 09:13:23--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u45-b06/jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin?AuthParam=1508903146_f5ba776a72e71785aa3526c9fb49f911  
Connecting to download.oracle.com   (download.oracle.com)|184.25.108.41|:80... connected.  
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found  
2017-10-25 09:13:26 ERROR 404: Not Found.  

download failed  
Oracle JDK 6 is NOT installed.  
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java6-installer (--configure):  
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

Is there any other way around?

Comment: May be oracle jdk download link broken or moved to different location.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get around this problem is to install phpmyadmin and the standard Java Development Kit (jdk) dependency package from the default Ubuntu repositories. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install default-jdk phpmyadmin
```

This will install a version of phpmyadmin that is as new or newer than the version of phpmyadmin that you have been trying to install in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. default-jdk is also a newer version than Oracle Java 6 in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: Unfortunately this gave the same error as before !

Comment: Your system is trying to install Oracle Java 6 again instead of the default Java from the default Ubuntu repositories that you need. Temporarily disable all Oracle lines in your software sources in `/etc/apt/sources.list` by prefacing each line to be disabled with a `#` character, run `sudo apt-get update` and try again.

Comment: You are right But I don't see any oracle lines in **sources.list** file.

Comment: Never mind **Karel** it might be the firewall in my office blocking the download.

Comment: Oracle Java 6 is getting old. Oracle Java 6 will receive extended support until December, 2018, but you should consider installing the newer default-jdk instead.

Comment: It wasn't firewall the problem still exists in the system. Apparently I can't install any software in my Ubuntu.

Comment: The only currently supported versions of Ubuntu are Ubuntu 14.04, 16.04 17.04 and 17.10. If you are using an unsupported version of Ubuntu please update it to a supported version or else backup your files and reinstall  a supported version of  Ubuntu. The latest supported Long Term Support (LTS) version of Ubuntu is Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Thanks **Karel** I moved to 16.04 and It worked like a charm !!!